# Twitter integration in android phonegap

Tags: android, twitter, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to develope a twitter login integration using phonegap 2.7.0 i followed a code
http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms
and i included all plugins and twitter frame work but i found that those plugins are not compact able with phonegap 2.7.0. Anybody know which will be the correct twitter plugins,.js,.h,.m files for phonegap 2.7.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a [service](https://github.com/k-rudy/phonegap-twitter-timeline) and detailed decription on how to make it working for both Android and iOS. It uses InAppBrowser plugin and works for PhoneGap 3.1.0.